# PHP code does not pass variable to 2nd php from foreach loop

Tags: php

I have this code in my 1st php file that creates a drop down list.  It works fine.  However I am struggling with getting the data to the 2nd php file.   The variable is not posted to the 2nd file.  I am not sure how to use $_POST in to select the MembersId value the array. Here is code in 1st file.

```
 <form method = "post" action = "LastMeetingAttendancebyDate.php">
  <select name="user">

    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <option value="<?= $user['MembersId'] ?>">
       <?= $user['lastName'] ?>, <?= $user['firstName'] ?> <?= 
    $user['callSign'] ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In the 2nd file I have:

```
  <?php
  $member_id = $_POST['MembersId'];
  ?>
```

I have left out the sql.   It currently runs but errors out as the variable is null in the sql.

Comment: err. that should be `$_POST['user']` not `$_POST['MembersId']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the form element is called `user` then you would look for `user` rather than `MembersId` in the POST array

```
# in LastMeetingAttendancebyDate.php

$member_id=isset( $_POST['user'] ) ? $_POST['user'] : false;
if( $member_id ){
    /* do interesting things */
    echo $member_id;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, this question should be closed as a typo.